# Increase the bound element in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Gets or Sets the bound element,Implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` which enables the bound element to refresh itself whenever the value changes.

```
public string number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number.Number + 1;
        }
        set
        {
            _number.Number  = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("number");
        }
    }
```

Then i want to display the number on a label

HTML

```
 <Label  Content="{Binding Path=number}" Height="28" Name="label1" Width="108" />
```

But when I execute the code, the number will be displayed correctly, but it close and execute again, the old value displayed...my problem is how to display the last incremented value in label after restarting application?

---

*Important Note:*
When first time i execute, the value of number is 1, and then fill the form with some data and it saved to the database , then the number will increase to 2. Then i close my whole application and run again, the label displayed the value 1. I want to display 2...that's the problem

Comment: If you close and execute again what? The entire application? In that case the behaviour you are experiencing is normal.

Comment: When first time i execute, the value of number is 1, and then fill the form with some data and it saved to the database ,  then the number will increase to 2. Then i close my whole application and run again, the label displayed the value 1. I want to display 2...that's the problem

Comment: If you want to persist between sessions of the application, including system shutdown, you need to store your data outside of memory.  This means you have many options, including but not limited to, User/App settings, database, XML or other flat file, registry, etc. You need to gather this stored value and display/increment it accordingly.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but please reconsider how you have implemented the increment. I think it's generally a bad idea for a property's `get` to return a different value than was given to `set`. With data binding in particular, suppose the binding decides to update from the UI to the data source; so the current UI value (`2`) is passed to `set`, then the property change event is raised, causing the UI to query the property again and receive `3` -- this could lead to infinite increments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string number
{
    get
    {
        number += 1;
        return _number.Number;
    }
    set
    {
        _number.Number = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All properies-objects are stored in memory and memory gets cleaned on app close. When you are launching application each property is instantiated by default values unless you will set it explicitly. That's why every time you start app value gets "refreshed". 
To have property that will not be application-lifetime dependent - you should put it into some external storage. Either file, database or somewhere else:

Store number to a file:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("storage.txt");
file.WriteLine(_number);
file.Close();
```

And reinitialize it:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
{
    _number = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not actually setting the value of _number, you are merely returning the value + 1.

in Thejaks's answer the property is used for the increment, however I would think incrementing _number.Number (+=1 or ++) is better.

EDIT: - ok so to clarify the solution as I would suggest:

```
public string number
    {
        get
        {
            _number.Number += 1;
            return _number.Number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number.Number  = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not answering question.

Comment: it is, but perhaps I need to clarify

Comment: Actual problem is that OP is trying to restore property value after app restart.

Comment: Actually its very confusing as there is little information as to what he is trying to achieve, perhaps you are right the concern is that it is not saving the number. That said I don't see how the incremental will ever work when, as far as the code shows, the value is never actually incremented. I assumed the value of _number.Number was being saved, but it was only ever saving as its initial value of 1 presumably set through code.

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza If OP is attempting to persist to the database based on `_number`, this would solve the problem, though.

Comment: @JineshG You need to post how you are saving to the database.

Comment: @JineshG: It is now a matter of figuring out how you are saving the value of _number.Number. If you do not save this anywhere (file, database etc) then Anatolii Gabuza is right and you will need to implement something of the sort of solution that he has suggest AS WELL AS the solution I have suggested.